# How to install `babel` in Texmaker?

Tags: packages, texmaker, babel, input-encodings

How do I install babel language pack in Texmaker? I want to use `\usepackage[swedish]{babel}` in Texmaker. At the moment,

```
Jag är bäst
```

in Texmaker gives

> Jag r bst

in the PDF. I use Windows 8.

Comment: @jotagah Thank you for the comment! Yeah indeed, I use Miktex. The link you posted didnt work. "404 - File or directory not found."

Comment: You don't need to install babel (unless you get an error babel.sty not found), but your document obviously doesn't load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[insert encoding of your file]{inputenc}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\today
Hur installerar jag Babel språkpaket i Texmaker?

Jag är bäst
\end{document}
```

Comment: Herbert, how many languages do you actually know? ;-)

Comment: Thank you! \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} solved my problem. I don't know what it did, but it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

UTF 8 encoding is needed, because 'Jag är bäst' contains character which aren't supported by the default encoding of LaTeX.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer by providing the relevant code and necessary explanations.